# SVM linear freezes

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, scikit-learn, blas

I am using scikit-learn's SVMLinear and it freezes in the middle of a grid search.

```
[Parallel(n_jobs=2)]: Done  18 jobs       | elapsed: 54.2min
[CV] C=1.0 ...........................................................
[CV] .................................. C=1.0, score=0.737288 - 6.8min
[CV] C=1.0 ...........................................................
[CV] .................................. C=1.0, score=0.735876 - 4.8min
[CV] C=10.0 ..........................................................
[CV] ................................. C=10.0, score=0.717514 - 3.9min
[CV] C=10.0 ..........................................................
[CV] ................................. C=10.0, score=0.714689 - 2.5min
[CV] C=10.0 ..........................................................
[CV] ................................. C=10.0, score=0.723164 - 4.3min
[CV] C=10.0 ..........................................................
```

My dataset:

```
sample size = 3500    
no. of features = 42900    
target = 0 and 1
```

I have not scaled the data though, if that is a possible problem. But I want confirm it has stopped working as my CPU shows low activity for some time and check if there are other possibilities, like are the features too large.

BTW, I cannot  get it to run in multithread reliably (need to manually set it using htop). I have installed Xianyi's OpenBLAS, but otherwise quite clueless on what's going on in my system with these BLAS stuff (or how to manage them).

Comment: Which OS? Is OpenBLAS [built with OpenMP support](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/computational_performance.html#linear-algebra-libraries)?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04. Now I have tried n_jobs = 1 in my grid search, so far so good no freezes. with n_jobs = 2 seems to consume much more memory and actually slows things down (4GB RAM). I suppose multithreading is irrelevant if I use n-jobs =1...?

Comment: Again, is your OpenBLAS built with OpenMP support? If so, get rid of it.